Allocation model in Power query
I want to create a simple allocation model in power query which will allocate inbound inventory to open orders. I have 2 tables as shown below. The first table is showing the open orders by SKU and then second table is showing inbound inventory by SKU which are going to available to allocate on multiple dates.
The final result would be a table that shows allocated units for each SKU and the dates on which they got fully allocated. If it is not fully allocated then the last date of allocation to be available.
Order and Inbound Tables

Final Table after Allocation

I have tried adding index to inbound inventory by date available and then using helper columns to allocate but it is not that robust and needs tweaking as the inbound table would change almost every day.
I am thinking of using iterative logic to allocate units as I have done it before in VBA with loop function but I am not able to figure this out.
Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Some questions about your tables:   - Why is the Date for SKU=3 6/28  when the order cannot be completely filled until 6/29?  - Will your Open Order table ever have the same SKU in more than one row?

I wrote it incorrectly. It should have been 6/29.
The open order will not have the sku repeated.

In M-Code for Power Query:You will need to alter the two Source lines to reflect your actual Table namesEdited to allow for Open SKU's with no matching Inbound SKU's
let

//Read in the Two Tables
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="OpenOrders"]}[Content],
    #"Open Orders" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"SKU", Int64.Type}, {"Open Orders", Int64.Type}}),
    Source2 = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Inbound"]}[Content],
    #"Inbound Inventory" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source2,{
        {"SKU", Int64.Type}, {"Inbound Inventory", Int64.Type}, {"Available Date", type date}}),

//Join the tables
    #"Join tables" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Open Orders","SKU",#"Inbound Inventory","SKU", "Joined", JoinKind.LeftOuter),

//Add the computed columns
    #"Added Allocated Units" = Table.AddColumn(#"Join tables","Allocated Units", each 
        List.Min({[Open Orders], List.Sum([Joined][Inbound Inventory])??0}), Int64.Type),
    #"Added Remaining Units" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Allocated Units","Remaining Units", each 
        List.Sum([Joined][Inbound Inventory])??0 - [Allocated Units]  , Int64.Type),
    #"Added Date" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Remaining Units","Date", (r)=>
        List.First(
        List.Select(
            List.Generate(
                ()=>[a = r[Allocated Units] - r[Joined][Inbound Inventory]{0}, d= r[Joined][Available Date]{0}, idx=0],
                each [idx] < Table.RowCount(r[Joined]),
                each [a = [a] - r[Joined][Inbound Inventory]{[idx]+1}, d = r[Joined][Available Date]{[idx]+1}, idx=[idx]+1],
                each {[a],[d]}),
            each _{0}<=0)){1}?, type date),

//Remove the now unneeded "Joined" column
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Date",{"Joined"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"



Hi Ron, Thanks for the help. It is working partially as I did not mention one scenario that could happen. There are times when there is no SKU in the inbound table that matches the SKU in the open order table. The current logic is allocating those SKU's also. Can you please let me know how it can be fixed.

Any case where the match is not found the allocated units should show 0 and the dates as null.

@HARJITSINGH Just a matter of adding few strategically places ?'s. The double ?? is the coalesce operator which is a short way of checking for null and replacing it with 0 which is what you get with a missing inbound SKU. The single ? will return a null if there is no existing item in the list (or no list at all) which is the case for the date algorithm.

Amazing. Thanks. You see to be a pro at this. I am trying to learn but not able to find a structured resource to learn Power query M language. Can you please recommend any good source to get better?

you can try this:

create relationship between two tables


then you only need to create one measure. The rest column you just drag to the table visual.
Measure =
IF (
    SUM ( 'Order'[Open Orders] ) > SUM ( Inbound[Inbound] ),
    0,
    SUM ( Inbound[Inbound] ) - SUM ( 'Order'[Open Orders] )
)


